# How do I give successive CSS classes different colors (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, css

I have annotated text, and I'd like certain annotated words to be color-coded along with their annotations, but I don't want to have to do it manually. Is there a way to have javascript (or jquery) or even css make the first `class="Noted"` green, then the second blue, and then on the fifth go back to green, and to do the same with the corresponding `class="note"`s?

Comment: is the class of "noted" on inline elements.. like a span, any way you can give a use case sample and any browser restrictions?

Comment: No browser restrictions for the moment. They're all inline elements. I figured out how to get the `<span class="Note">`s in the margins, but now I just need to color code them so it's not too confusing.

Comment: Ok this is what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfwPT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your jsFiddle you could use something along these lines to get the result you're after:

```
p:nth-child(5n+1) .Noted, p:nth-child(5n+1) .Annotation {color: green}
```

as demonstarted in [this modification of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfwPT/2/)

Answer (score 3):

you can do this using :nth-child you will need something like jQuery for support for IE though.. working on that...

here's a first fiddle for a CSS only version [http:http://jsfiddle.net/zhQ67/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/zhQ67/2/) **** FIDDLE updated with new code below ****

CSS:

```
.noted:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: green;
}

.noted:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}


.noted:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: yellow;
}


.noted:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

**final update** using thirtdots updated code and including some jQuery for IE - [JSBIN Page](http://jsbin.com/uyodo3/2)

Comment: Assuming (as you do here) that there are four different colours, the formula should be (4n+x) for each selector. So (4n+1) for green, (4n+2) for red, (4n+3) for yellow, and (4n+4) for blue.

Comment: That's so awesome, but I don't know why it's not working in my version: http://jsfiddle.net/QNjRN/2/

Comment: Gareth, yes you are right and I've updated the the fiddle and code, it was too quick a mock-up..yes I'm assuming four colours as per the question, but if there's more just the  "n" number would change

Comment: It's not working for you because you have your `span`s inside other tags. Try this tweaked version: http://jsfiddle.net/QNjRN/3/

Comment: @Jono the spans (children) are only counted when they're children of the same element

Comment: @thirtydot.. thanks for the updated fiddle code to work for Jono's use case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all elements with getElementsByClass an then simply iterate through them, giving every single one and it's corresponding element class="note" a different color.

Comment: How does one iterate through them? Also, I've been told there's no such thing as getElementsByClass

Comment: @Jono: Several current browsers implement `getElementsByClass` and there are many simple implementions for ones that don't. Just google for "getElementsByClass". Or use one of many JavaScript frameworks/libraries such as jQuery, that provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In jquery.....set the colors as you see fit. [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuZ92/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Noted").each(function(i,e){
    switch(i%4){
        case 0: $(this).css({color:"#f00"});break;
        case 1: $(this).css({color:"#0f0"});break;
        case 2: $(this).css({color:"#00f"});break;
        case 3: $(this).css({color:"#ff9"});break;
        case 4: $(this).css({color:"#f90"});break;       
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try encapsulating your elements inside a container. It will make the children selection much easier.

```
<div id="parent">
     <span class="note">Green</span>, <span class="note">blue</span> 
     then <span class="note">red</span>.
</div>
```

then, the js :

```
<script>
var  children = document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('*')
    ,colours = ['green','blue','red','orange']
    ,i,j=0,max;

for (i = 0, max = children.length; i<max; i++) {
    if(children[i].getAttribute('class') == 'note') {
       children[i].setAttribute('style','color:' + colours[j]);
       j++;
       if (j>colours.length) {
          j = 0;
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is being generated by a server side script, you could have the script assign a class based on which Annotation is being generated, then in the stylesheet, assign a color to that class, like so:

```
.note1 { //Corresponds to class='note1'
  color: green; //or whatever you want
}
.note2 { //Corresponds to class='note2'
  color: blue; //or whatever you want
}
/* and so on */
```

If the HTML is simply being written statically, then assign the class corresponding to how it defined in the stylesheet, depending on the color you want.

If they are children, you could use something along the lines of clairesuzy's solution.

The other option is to assign all of them as class `note` and then have an javascript that colors everything marked as class `note` based on a predefined order that you set.

That would probably be along the lines of something like this (using jQuery):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hs8Nm/

```
<p class="note">Note 1</p>
<p class="note">Note 2</p>
<p class="note">Note 3</p>
<p class="note">Note 4</p>
```

and the corresponding Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ['green','blue','orange','yellow',"FFFFF0"]; //Assign your color order here.
  $('.note').each(function(index){
      this.css('color',colors[index%5]);  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp). You can get the first, second, third, and so on element in a list of matching occurences.

Comment: But then how would I tell it that the sixth element should be treated as the first?

Comment: Use `:nth-child()`. `.Noted:nth-child(5n+1){color:green}` will turn the first, sixth, eleventh, etc. elements' text colour green. Be aware though, this doesn't work in IE. For IE support you'll have to use this through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Cycle classes</title>

<style>
.blue {

    background-color: blue;
}

.green {

    background-color: green;
}

.yellow {

    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<script>


$(document).ready( function() {
$(".Noted").each(function(i) {
    var classes = ['green','blue','yellow'];
    $(this).addClass(classes[i % classes.length])
});

})

 </script>



</head>

<body>

 <div class="Noted">hello</div>
 <div class="Noted">world</div>
 <div class="Noted">it works</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: more explanation: the i is the iteration count. We use that to cycle through the classes array. The ".Noted" selector will get all the elements with the .Noted class and call the function for all of them... jquery makes the code fun :)